# Trying to retain a user selection from a drop down menu across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, local

So I have written a script for a knowledge management page which allows the user to select from a list of states in a drop down menu, and the content on the page is tailored to the state selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="Arizona"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".Arizona").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="Arkansas"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".Arkansas").show();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Etc... for about 22 states. 
What I need it to do is to retain the user's selection between pages within the domain. 
What I have tried so far:

```
localStorage.setItem("state", "Arizona");
localStorage.getItem('state');
```

I am fairly new to JS, and am having issues getting this to work. It does not seem to retain the value. Ideally I need to have 2 versions, one using local storage and one using session storage as we have internal and external customers with different needs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a closer look at the `localStorage` api. There is an event fired whenever a new item is added to storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

That being said, state management in the browser across multiple clients in offline/online modes with on-the-fly updates is not a trivial "here let me just whip up a script" problem.

A complete solution might include websockets for server communication and a database or in-memory cache acting as the state manager for the clients.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have should work. I need to take a look at the full javascript code.